# excel VBA, trying to print an area?

Tags: vba, printing

I'm making a big workbook at the moment, trying to get it so at the end of each month I run a macro which generates the new sheet.

I've got this sorted now.

Next is having a macro which gives the user an option to Print only the relevant information from the sheet.

This gets kind of complicated! As certain columns in the midst of the data shouldn't be printed, however I still want them to be visible at all other times.

**My solution:**

(note I am pretty new to VBA, and this was quite complicated for me so I just used macro recorder)

I split it up into two steps, one is a macro is called by pressing 'Create Print Area' button on sheet and the next is a macro called by a 'Send To Printer' button

Create Print Area Macro - Hides all undesired columns then highlights all cells from "$B$1:$Y$567", then makes this the print area.

Send to Printer Macro - Sends the print area to printer. It has the settings of A3 size, fiting columns to width, having $1:$1 as the print title and otherwise just default settings I think. I then  unhide the cells hidden from running the Print Area Macro.

**The problem:** So far the first macro appears to be working, and by in large the second macro seems to be working. However despite printing in the right size, right number of columns and correct print titles, it's printing all the rows in the sheet. (ie not cutting off at Row 567). This isn't a huge problem as I only have 10 rows of data after 567, but it's a bit annoying as it means an extra unnecessary page is produced as well as it looking a bit messy, Ideally I could get rid of these additional rows printed.

**Any suggestions?** I've spent ages trying to figure it out without success.

**Attached is my code for the second macro (note long and messy as done with macro recorder).**

```
Sub printSheetSend()
'
' printSheetSend Macro
'

'
Application.Goto Reference:="Print_Area"
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$1"
    .PrintTitleColumns = ""
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$1:$Y$567"
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .LeftHeader = ""
    .CenterHeader = ""
    .RightHeader = ""
    .LeftFooter = ""
    .CenterFooter = ""
    .RightFooter = ""
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .PrintHeadings = False
    .PrintGridlines = False
    .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
    .PrintQuality = 600
    .CenterHorizontally = False
    .CenterVertically = False
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .Draft = False
    .PaperSize = xlPaperA3
    .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
    .Order = xlDownThenOver
    .BlackAndWhite = False
    .zoom = 100
    .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
    .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
    .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
    .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
    .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
    .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$1"
    .PrintTitleColumns = ""
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$1:$Y$567"
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .LeftHeader = ""
    .CenterHeader = ""
    .RightHeader = ""
    .LeftFooter = ""
    .CenterFooter = ""
    .RightFooter = ""
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .PrintHeadings = False
    .PrintGridlines = False
    .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
    .PrintQuality = 600
    .CenterHorizontally = False
    .CenterVertically = False
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .Draft = False
    .PaperSize = xlPaperA3
    .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
    .Order = xlDownThenOver
    .BlackAndWhite = False
    .zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 1
    .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
    .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
    .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
    .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
    .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
    .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$1"
    .PrintTitleColumns = ""
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$1:$Y$567"
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .LeftHeader = ""
    .CenterHeader = ""
    .RightHeader = ""
    .LeftFooter = ""
    .CenterFooter = ""
    .RightFooter = ""
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .PrintHeadings = False
    .PrintGridlines = False
    .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
    .PrintQuality = 600
    .CenterHorizontally = False
    .CenterVertically = False
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .Draft = False
    .PaperSize = xlPaperA3
    .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
    .Order = xlDownThenOver
    .BlackAndWhite = False
    .zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 0
    .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
    .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
    .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
    .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
    .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
    .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True

' ADD: send shit to printer here
Columns("G:G").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Columns("I:I").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Columns("L:L").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Columns("O:O").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Columns("T:T").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Columns("U:U").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Columns("V:V").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Range("B1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you thought about creating a new sheet, copying everything you want to that new sheet, printing the stuff on that new sheet, then deleting it? That can be done in vba btw.

Comment: Ah yeah that's not a bad idea! Ideally if there's and easy fix to what I've got now I'd rather do that (also would be interested in learning what's currently going on), but if not I could try that. I can have it so the sheet is literally printed physically and then is deleted automatically right? As the person who is using this sheet is not great at excel, and I will eventually have 14 sheets on workbook at the end of the year so I want to reduce clutter!

Comment: There might be an easy fix, but because the sample code you provided is very very long (because of macro recorder) I can't seem to find one. There probably is one but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Yeah fair enough! It's a pretty horrible chunk of code, I tried cutting it down and making it easier to follow earlier, but then it stopped working so I've just left it as is.

Comment: Just clarifying you meant I can have it so the sheet is literally printed physically and then is deleted automatically right?

Comment: Yes, essentially what would occur is that excel would create a new worksheet during runtime, then copy the data that you want to that spreadsheet. It would then set the print area to the data that it copied to that new sheet, then print that new sheet, then automatically delete it. However, I sincerely doubt that is possible to do in macro recorder.

Comment: Ah yep, that's probably outside of my abilities with code. I'll have a read up and attempt to code it though. Thanks! If you have any suggestions to code, let me know!

Comment: Give me a bit and I'll write you some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm writing this code to print Column A, B, and D and not print Column C.

```
A___B___C___D
1   2   3   4
1   2   3   4
1   2   3   4


Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim TotalRows as Long
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
ws.Name = "Delete"
TotalRows = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Copy
ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Copy
ws.Range("B1").PasteSpecial
ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Copy
ws.Range("C1").PasteSpecial
ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = ws.Range("A1:C" & TotalRows)
ws.PrintOut
Application.EnableEvents = False
ws.Delete
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

So if all goes well I will get a printout that looks like

```
A__B__D
1  2  4
1  2  4
1  2  4
```

To use this code you will have to modify it pretty heavily but I hope this can be a framework.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry all! Ignore this question!

Turns out someone had added comments to the spreadsheet and these were printing out as well.. Code is fine :)